# OnSave actions in NetBeans 6.9

Tags: netbeans

Is there any way to tell NetBeans to execute a specific action when saving a file? e.g. removing unused imports while saving a source file?

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting question... as I believe you would have to write a custom NetBeans plugin to do what you're wanting (the functionality isn't available out-of-the-box), and I've been looking for an excuse to explore NetBeans plugin development.

However, after spending a couple of hours reading tutorials and crawling through the javadocs... it's become clear that this subject is quite a big bite to chew, and probably way more involved than you're wanting.

---

I think the BEST suggestion is forget about removing unused imports at **save-time**, and instead perform this step at **build-time**.  NetBeans offers great integration with Ant and/or Maven (for build purposes it's basically just a GUI wrapper around those tools), and there are a number of Ant tasks out there that can do what you're wanting.  See:

http://ant.apache.org/external.html
(look for the "CleanImports" and "Importscrubber" tasks)

If your NetBeans project(s) are Maven-based, then you can always plug in one of these Ant tasks there using the [AntRun plugin for Maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

If you're not used to dealing with Ant or Maven *directly* in NetBeans, then just switch to the "Files" tab and look at your project's root directory.  If its a Maven project, the build script will be named `pom.xml`.  Otherwise, your project will generally be Ant-based and the build script will be named `build.xml`.  The documentation for these items above should make it fairly clear how to move forward from there.

---

I notice that those two Ant tasks haven't been updated in awhile, so if you run into issues you might want to check out the very popular and up-to-date [PMD system](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/), which has its own [documentation for integrating with NetBeans](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/integrations.html#netbeans).  However, the issue there is PMD is primarily for generating reports... I don't know if it can be used to actually take action and change source files.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but note that NB 7.1 lets you fix imports on the whole project at once: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB71#Organize_Imports_Hint

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice and NetBeans does not support it.

Comment: Could expand on this (why it's not good style) or provide some references (specifics about NetBeans not supporting this)?  Right now, your answer looks more like a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I resurrect this topic.

Well this code code is tested with Netbeans 7.4.
here I'm overriding the default save action in the actionPerformed method.
If you choose to do this by yourself create a new Action using the wizard then call the save action inside actionPerformed method.

```
package yourpackage;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.openide.awt.ActionID;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReference;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReferences;
import org.openide.awt.ActionRegistration;
import org.openide.util.NbBundle.Messages;

@ActionID(
        category = "File",
        id = "BZ.SaveAction"
)
@ActionRegistration(
        iconBase = "BZ/Save.png",
        displayName = "#CTL_SaveAction"
)
@ActionReferences({
    @ActionReference(path = "Menu/File", position = 750),
    @ActionReference(path = "Toolbars/File", position = 0),
    @ActionReference(path = "Shortcuts", name = "D-S")
})
@Messages("CTL_SaveAction=Save")
public final class SaveAction implements ActionListener {

    org.openide.actions.SaveAction sa = org.openide.util.actions.CallbackSystemAction.get(org.openide.actions.SaveAction.class);
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // custom code
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "custum message ");
        sa.performAction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Tools-> Options` select `Editor` there select `On Save Tab` now select `Java` from drop down menu. So, now select `Organize Imports` option. Hope this will help you.